# ios - Bulding an app that have push notification appear on a specific time interval

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, nsurlsession

I'm building my first application.

I'm making app where I'm doing some fetching from rss feed of web site and loading it to a TableView. What I want is next:
-to inform a user when new feed arrive, when my app is closed (user can set the time interval of update frequency in app settings page) - with Local Notification

I'm using NSURLSession for downloading data, storing it with Core Data, and want the Deployment Target to be iOS 7.1.
Just want to know is it possible and steps that I need to do to implement it correctly.

Comment: why to use PushNotification for this, you can use LocalNotification for this.

Comment: sorry, LocalNotification is actually what I wanted. *edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called Background Fetch. Background fetch can fetch data from your servers even when the app is not running.

Local notifications would be of no help here. Even when a local notification has been fired, user will have to click on it to fetch data.

Look it up. There is a pretty decent [tutorial here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/).

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty similar to what I have been doing...anyway the crucial thing in my app is that the user will be informed when new feed that is important to him arrive, so I must implement Local Notification.

Comment: @Milos When your app wakes up for background fetch, you can show a local notification there, can't you?